# Tensorflow Train.py error no variables

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been following dat tran's tutorial. When running train.py as instructed with "**ssd_inception_v2_coco_2017_11_17**" gave these:

```
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
```

an this error:

```
      File "C:path\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 1023, in unstack
          (axis, -value_shape.ndims, value_shape.ndims))
      ValueError: axis = 0 not in [0, 0)
```

I looked for that error and a solution was to use another network for training so I used "**faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco_2018_01_28**" which gave a bunch of warnings:

```
    WARNING:root:Variable [resnet_v1_101/conv1/BatchNorm/beta] not available in checkpoint
    WARNING:root:Variable [resnet_v1_101/conv1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
    WARNING:root:Variable [resnet_v1_101/conv1/BatchNorm/moving_mean] not available in checkpoint
    WARNING:root:Variable [resnet_v1_101/conv1/BatchNorm/moving_variance] not available in checkpoint
    WARNING:root:Variable [resnet_v1_101/conv1/weights] not available in checkpoint
```

and this error:

```
 File "C:path\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1251, in _build
     raise ValueError("No variables to save")
 ValueError: No variables to save
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify this line from the **pipeline.config** file:

from:

```
from_detection_checkpoint: false
```

to:

```
from_detection_checkpoint: true
```